# Access (mount) VHDX images

Tags: mount

Are there tools to access or mount VHDX images **on macOS** (Paragon VMDK Mounter for Mac OS X is not available anymore). Is a similar tool available?

I would like to access Windows Backup images.

I am using macOS 10.14 (Mojave) and both a free or paid solution would be OK.

**Edit**: I know that I can access the images with Windows but I would like to know if there is a way with macOS similar to the no more available Paragon Mounter)